# Google Fonts not appearing in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, asset-pipeline

Basic Question for the Rail geniuses out there:

So I created a new rails project and a new controller called `sessions` with action `new`

Snippet of  `new.html.erb`

```
   <div id="title">
        Title
    </div>
```

In `sessions.css.scss`

I used

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Damion);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu);

#title{
font-family: 'Damion', cursive;
}
```

to import the fonts and style the title. But for some reason, the title font is still not appearing in the damion font. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Damion');
```

use

```
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Damion');
```

Comment: @idude If that solved your issue please mark it as solved to help other folks who are searching for like this issue.